# string split by index / params?

Tags: c#, string, split

Just before I write my own function just wanted to check if there exists a function like  `string.split(string input, params int[] indexes)`  in the .NET library?
This function should split the string on indexes i pass to it.

Edit: I shouldn't have added the string.join sentence - it was confusing.

Comment: I assume the method should split the input string at each index element? So `string.Split("1234567", 2, 5) == { "12", "345", "67" }`? If so, there is no such method. If not, can you elaborate?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Split and Join have very different results and make your question confusing.

Comment: thats right, dlev. I take it by the hostility this thread is generating the answer is no.

Comment: @maxp Questions similar to this one are often the result of laziness on the questioner's part. In this case, I interpreted it as "I can't seem to find one; can anyone confirm before I write it?" In any case, no such function exists in the base-class library, but luckily writing your own is pretty simple. Good luck!

Comment: maxp: that's not hostility - but your question could have been better/clearer, e.g. by including an example of how you want to call the method and what it should return.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the `String` instance method [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.71).aspx).

```
string a = input.Substring(0, 10);
string b = input.Substring(10, 5);
string c = input.Substring(15, 3);
```

Comment: He still needs to make multiple method calls; I think he's looking for that *precise* method (though I'm pretty sure this *is* how he's going to implement it. Since he'll have to.)

Comment: @dlev, I see what you mean. I'm not sure a method that takes a set of split points would add much over the corresponding 'long' code though.

Comment: There's nothing inbuilt like that, but it could be made as toolset function; using a `params int[] indexes` parameter, which would simply loop the String.Substring calls and put the results in an array.

Comment: you can use a regex to split the string, and use quantifiers for the positions

Comment: This might be useful. Just iterate `input.Substring(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are given by some generator. I'm looking at using `Range[x..y]` with `Regex` being the *generator*. If my idea doesn't work, then this is what I will implement. Concise.

Answer (score 10):

All other answers just seemed too complicated, so I took a stab.

```
using System.Linq;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by specified indexes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The original string.</param>
    /// <param name="index">An index that delimits the substrings in this string.</param>
    /// <returns>An array whose elements contain the substrings in this instance that are delimited by one or more indexes.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="index" /> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">An <paramref name="index" /> is less than zero or greater than the length of this instance.</exception>
    public static string[] SplitAt(this string source, params int[] index)
    {
        index = index.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        string[] output = new string[index.Length + 1];
        int pos = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; pos = index[i++])
            output[i] = source.Substring(pos, index[i] - pos);

        output[index.Length] = source.Substring(pos);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: cool method. Would you please make a safe analog of this, where exception will not be thrown if one of indexes is out of range? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Burying the exceptions would break convention. When working with Strings, the convention in c# is to throw errors when the indexes are out of range. And, since this is more a method for utility and reuse, I've opted to add documentation for those exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

The Split method divides a string based on a recognition pattern. Perfect for breaking down comma seperated lists etc.

But you are right, there are no built in string methods to achieve what you want.

Comment: This actually answers the question. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer *your* generalized question, but in what is most likely the common case (or at least the case for which I was searching for an answer when I came upon this SO question) where `indexes` is a single `int`, this extension method is a little cleaner than returning a `string[]` array, especially in C# 7.

For what it's worth, I benchmarked using `string.Substring()` against creating two `char[]` arrays, calling `text.CopyTo()` and returning two strings by calling `new string(charArray)`.  Using `string.Substring()` was roughly twice as fast.

#### C# 7 syntax

[jdoodle.com example](http://jdoodle.com/a/yKS)

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static (string left, string right) SplitAt(this string text, int index) => 
        (text.Substring(0, index), text.Substring(index));
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var (left, right) = "leftright".SplitAt(4);
        Console.WriteLine(left);
        Console.WriteLine(right);
    }
}
```

#### C# 6 syntax

[jdoodle.com example](http://jdoodle.com/a/yKT)

Note: Using `Tuple<string, string>` in versions prior to C# 7 doesn't save much in the way of verbosity and it might actually be cleaner to just return a `string[2]` array.

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    // I'd use one or the other of these methods, and whichever one you choose, 
    // rename it to SplitAt()

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Tuple<string, string> TupleSplitAt(this string text, int index) => 
        Tuple.Create<string, string>(text.Substring(0, index), text.Substring(index));

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static string[] ArraySplitAt(this string text, int index) => 
        new string[] { text.Substring(0, index), text.Substring(index) };
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Tuple<string, string> stringsTuple = "leftright".TupleSplitAt(4);
        Console.WriteLine("Tuple method");
        Console.WriteLine(stringsTuple.Item1);
        Console.WriteLine(stringsTuple.Item2);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Array method");
        string[] stringsArray = "leftright".ArraySplitAt(4);
        Console.WriteLine(stringsArray[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(stringsArray[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string[] Split(this string source, params int[] sizes)
    {
        var length = sizes.Sum();
        if (length > source.Length) return null;

        var resultSize = sizes.Length;
        if (length < source.Length) resultSize++;

        var result = new string[resultSize];

        var start = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < resultSize; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 == resultSize)
            {
                result[i] = source.Substring(start);
                break;
            }

            result[i] = source.Substring(start, sizes[i]);
            start += sizes[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAt(this string source, params int[] index)
{
    var indices = new[] { 0 }.Union(index).Union(new[] { source.Length });

    return indices
                .Zip(indices.Skip(1), (a, b) => (a, b))
                .Select(_ => source.Substring(_.a, _.b - _.a));
}

var s = "abcd";

s.SplitAt(); // "abcd"
s.SplitAt(0); // "abcd"
s.SplitAt(1); // "a", "bcd"
s.SplitAt(2); // "ab", "cd"
s.SplitAt(1, 2) // "a", "b", "cd"
s.SplitAt(3); // "abc", "d"
```

Comment: getting error `Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple 2' is not defined or imported` at `=> (a, b)`

Comment: @NitinSawant you need to install the NuGet package ```System.ValueTuple``` for .NET 4.6.2 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

There is always regular expressions.

Here's an example from which one can expand upon:

```
 string text = "0123456789ABCDEF";
 Match m = new Regex("(.{7})(.{4})(.{5})").Match(text);
 if (m.Success)
 {
     var result = new string[m.Groups.Count - 1];
     for (var i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
         result[i - 1] = m.Groups[i].Value;
 }
```

Here's a function that encapsulates the above logic:

```
    public static string[] SplitAt(this string text, params int[] indexes)
    {
        var pattern = new StringBuilder();
        var lastIndex = 0;
        foreach (var index in indexes)
        {
            pattern.AppendFormat("(.{{{0}}})", index - lastIndex);
            lastIndex = index;
        }
        pattern.Append("(.+)");

        var match = new Regex(pattern.ToString()).Match(text);
        if (! match.Success)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("text cannot be split by given indexes");
        }

        var result = new string[match.Groups.Count - 1];
        for (var i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
            result[i - 1] = match.Groups[i].Value;
        return result;            
    }
```

This was written rather quickly but I believe it illustrates my points and emphasizes my points to author of comment, Michael.

Comment: Hello Jack, and welcome to stack overflow.
I disagree with your suggestion because it has some efficiency problems and because that's nor what regular expressions are meant for. RegEx's are used for pattern finding and this is not what the OP is trying to do. Efficiency wise, you're already itterating through 3 groups - wouldn't it be more logical and efficent to just call split 3 times?

Comment: @Michael: Using regex brings with it error checking of the content.  Handwriting multiple lines with offsets is error prone and tedious. Regarding efficiency, if you're meaning performance, I don't believe that thinking about performance in this case is well targeted.  I am more concerned with robustness and completeness.  As I said this is an example upon which one can expand.  One could easily put this logic in a function matching the OP calling signature and from then on eliminating the need to call substring() multiple times.

Comment: Using RegEx for this task is a very poor choice. IMO Would be rejected - sent back to be rewritten by the coder - by any experienced team leader or code reviewer. The result is difficult to read. Its also confusing to anyone who encounters it: raises the question as to what it is trying to do; its unexpected. RegEx is appropriate for pattern recognition; is not appropriate for manipulating string indices.

Answer (score 0):

Version with "List< string >" as return.

Caller

```
string iTextLine = "02121AAAARobert Louis StevensonXXXX"
int[] tempListIndex = new int[] {
    // 0 -  // 0number  (exclude first)
    5,      // 1user
    9,      // 2name
    31      // role
};  

// GET - words from indexes
List<string> tempWords = getListWordsFromLine(iTextLine, tempListIndex);
```

method

```
/// <summary>
/// GET - split line in parts using index cuts
/// </summary>
/// <param name="iListIndex">Input List of indexes</param>
/// <param name="iTextLine">Input line to split</param>
public static List<string> getListWordsFromLine(string iTextLine, int[] iListIndex)
{
    // INIT
    List<string> retObj = new List<string>(); 
    int currStartPos = 0;
    // GET - clear index list from dupl. and sort it
    int[] tempListIndex = iListIndex.Distinct()
                                    .OrderBy(o => o)
                                    .ToArray();
    // CTRL
    if (tempListIndex.Length != iListIndex.Length)
    {
        // ERR
        throw new Exception("Input  iListIndex contains duplicate indexes");
    }


    for (int jj = 0; jj < tempListIndex.Length; ++jj)
    {
        try
        {
            // SET - line chunk
            retObj.Add(iTextLine.Substring(currStartPos,
                                           tempListIndex[jj] - currStartPos));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // SET - line is shorter than expected
            retObj.Add(string.Empty);                    
        }                
        // GET - update start position
        currStartPos = tempListIndex[jj];
    }
    // SET
    retObj.Add(iTextLine.Substring(currStartPos));  
    // RET
    return retObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the `Range` class to implement a solution.

My use case was to convert standard property names - e.g. `CustomerName`, `WindowSize`, etc. - into a JSON property name that would still be easy to read - as in `customer_name`, `window_size`.

Creating a `JsonNamingPolicy` descendent, I overrode the `ConvertName` method with the following implementation:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a property name like "CustomerName" and converts to "customer_name"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">the propery name</param>
        /// <returns>property conversion</returns>
        public override string ConvertName(string name) {
            //  using Regex to look for caps: "([A-Z]+)"
            Match[] matches = regex.Matches(name)
                .ToArray();

            if (!matches.Any()) {
                //  no capitals to match
                return name;
            }

            if (matches.Length == 1) {
                //  one match
                return name.ToLower();
            }

            //  multiple matches - we could use StringBuilder
            string[] parts = new string[matches.Length];

            int index = 0;

            //  this is somewhat verbose for debugging purposes
            while (index < matches.Length) {
                //  get our match
                Match m = matches[index];
                //  calculate range length
                int length = index + 1 < matches.Length ?
                    //  return the start of the next match
                    (matches[index + 1]).Index : 
                    //  return the end of the string
                    name.Length;

                //  create the range
                Range range = (m.Index..length);
                //  insert the part
                parts[index] = (name[range]).ToLower();
                //  increment the indexer
                ++index;
            }

            //  construct property name
            return string.Join("_", parts);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I could use `StringBuilder` as some people will likely prefer. I don't anticipate performance problems as this is a *one and done* scenario.

That being said, *if I needed* to serialize tons of data to go across the wire, I would likely forego this process altogether and design my properties with the desired naming convention.

For completeness, here is the source class:

```cs
    // trimmed to the necessary bits for brevity
    public class LaunchParameters : ILoadable {
        #region     properties
        [JsonIgnore]
        string ILoadable.Directory { get; } = CONFIG_DIR;
        [JsonIgnore]
        string ILoadable.FileName { get; } = CONFIG_FILE;
        public Size WindowSize { get; set; } = new(1024, 768);
        public string Title { get; init; } = "GLX Game";
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Application => Title.Replace(" ", "_");
        public string Label { get; init; }
        public Version Version { get; init; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string WindowTitle => $"{Title} Window";
        public string LogPath { get; init; } = @".\.logs";
        public string CrashLogPath { get; init; } = @".\.crash_logs";
        #endregion  properties
    }
```

... and the resulting JSON:

```json
{
  "window_size": {
    "is_empty": false,
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 768
  },
  "title": "GLX Game",
  "label": null,
  "version": null,
  "log_path": ".\\.logs",
  "crash_log_path": ".\\.crash_logs"
}
```